# SVG animate dotted line around cicle

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm trying to draw a line animation of a circle. I need this to work on mobile so opted for SVG. I have a perfect working example, but it is very inefficient and makes the other animations on the page stutter.

This is what I currently have and what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/sj76ysqs/

```
<svg class="bean-halo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 500 500"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
   style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">

    <path d="M200,200 " id="bean-halo" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-dasharray="0.1,10" />
</svg>

(function() {
    var i = 0,
        circle = document.getElementById('bean-halo'),
        angle = 0,
        radius = 167,
        interval = 20,
        d, radians, x, y, e;

    window.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        angle -= 5;
        angle %= 360;
        radians = (angle / 180) * Math.PI;
        x = 250 + Math.cos(radians) * radius;
        y = 250 + Math.sin(radians) * radius;
        e = circle.getAttribute('d');
        d = e + (i === 0 ? ' M ' : ' L ') + x + ' ' + y;
        if (angle === -5 && i !== 0) {
            window.clearInterval(window.timer);
            this.beanHaloisDrawn = 1;
        }
        circle.setAttribute('d', d);
        i++;
    }.bind(this), interval);
})()
```

I'd like to use the following technique or something similar, but don't know enough about SVGs to do this: http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

I've also though about having a static dotted line that is masked by an animated line that reveals it, but again, I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: The solution has to work on an element with a image as background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just manipulating stroke-dasharray of a circle

```
<svg class="bean-halo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 500 500"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
   style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">

    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" id="bean-halo" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-dasharray="0.1,20000" />
</svg>
```

together with something like this...

```
(function() {
            var angle = 0;
            var circle = document.getElementById('bean-halo');
            var dash="0.1,10 ";
            var interval = 20;


            window.timer = window.setInterval(function() {

                circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", dash + " 0, 20000");
                dash = dash + "0.1,10 ";
                if (angle >= 360) window.clearInterval(window.timer);
                angle += 10.1/360;
            }.bind(this), interval);
        })()
```

If you don't want to use javascript you'll have to do the interpolation yourself by creating a huge animate with all the intermediate steps. I've done 4 below but you get the gist. You could create the attribute using javascript and a loop though.

```
<svg class="bean-halo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 

xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 500 500"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
   style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">

    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-width="1" stroke="red" fill="white">

        <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" 

values="1,10,0,20000;1,10,1,10,0,20000;1,10,1,10,1,10,0,20000;1,10,1,10,1,10,1,10,0,20000" 

dur="4s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
   </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works well, but I was hoping to not use setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Animation trick using two circles, no coding required:-

```
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="1,6" stroke-width="1"  stroke="red" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="1200,1200 " stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="white" fill="none">
       <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="1200" dur="4s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: That looks awesome! Is there a way to get those lines to look like dots?

Comment: Very clever, provided the circle isn't drawn on top of anything else of course.

Comment: stroke-linecap="round" for dots as you already have in your original question.

Comment: Ah damnit. The circle will be drawn on an image :/

Comment: Yeah, this *animation trick* has some caveat, which is to mask the border of top circle with the background image so it looks seamless.